# How to change image every second in map react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image

Im trying to change my image every second in react inside of a map. However this doesnt seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
function ImageGrid() {
const {shell, gridImage} = styles
const squishAnimals = [
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(1).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(2).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(3).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(4).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(5).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(6).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(7).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(8).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(9).png'
];
const [images, setImages] = useState(squishAnimals);
const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

function changeBackgroundImage() {
    let newCurrentImg = 0;
    const noOfImages = images.length;

    if (currentImage !== noOfImages - 1) {
        newCurrentImg += currentImage;
    }

    setCurrentImage(newCurrentImg);
}

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => changeBackgroundImage(), 1000);

    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

});

return (
    <div className={shell}>
        {squishAnimals.map((image, index) => {
            return (
                index === 4 ?
                    <img className={gridImage} src={images[currentImage]} alt={`${index}-${image}`}/> :
                    <img className={gridImage} src={image} alt={`${index}-${image}`}/>
            )
        })}
    </div>
);
```

}

Any help as to why it may not be working would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Any time you are iterating in your render you should set a `key` prop as detailed here, https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you immediately cancel the `interval` in useEffect. I believe you want to return a cleanup function to clear the interval id.

```
function ImageGrid() {
const {shell, gridImage} = styles
const squishAnimals = [
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(1).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(2).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(3).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(4).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(5).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(6).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(7).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(8).png',
    '/SquishAnimalDemo(9).png'
];
const [images, setImages] = useState(squishAnimals);
const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

function changeBackgroundImage() {
    let newCurrentImg = 0;
    const noOfImages = images.length;

    if (currentImage !== noOfImages - 1) {
        newCurrentImg += currentImage;
    }

    setCurrentImage(newCurrentImg);
}

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => changeBackgroundImage(), 1000);

    return () => { 
       if (interval) {
          clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }
});

return (
    <div className={shell}>
        {squishAnimals.map((image, index) => {
            return (
                index === 4 ?
                    <img className={gridImage} src={images[currentImage]} alt={`${index}-${image}`} key={images[currentImage]}/> :
                    <img className={gridImage} src={image} alt={`${index}-${image}`} key = {`${index}-${image}`}/>
            )
        })}
    </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a code example to better explain this? I do not know how I would add the clean up for the interval

Comment: @OliverDarby could you try the code snippet i posted? I returned a function from `useEffect` which acts as a cleanup function for useEffect hook.

Comment: Sorry my bad, unfortunately it did not work, nothing changed from this either it just stayed the same as before

Comment: What is currently happening? Will you be willing to create a JSFiddle to help reproduce it?